# Can the break-even of a straddle be lower than the implied move?

Tags: options, option-pricing, volatility, implied-volatility

Let us consider a two day option:

- 1 day having a baseline vol of 16%
- 1 day having an event for which we want to find the implied move, higher than 16%

Is it possible that the price of the straddle in % of spot is lower than the implied move we would have found.

For example let us imagine the the straddle is trading at 18%, giving us:

$$ \frac{16^2+EventVol^2}{2}\simeq18^2$$

$$EventVol\simeq19.8$$
Dividing by ~ $\sqrt{252}$ to get a daily implied move of about 1.4%.

Would it be possible that the 2 day straddle trades at 2% in % of spot, in this example? Are there any cases where that may be true?

Comment: Are you asking about the price of the 2day option or the 1 day ?

Comment: The 2 day option, edited for clarity